# how a button performs a jquery action

Tags: jquery

I have HTMl like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".nav").attr("id", function(i) {
        return "cat" + i;
      });
      $("ul.nav").append("<li class='ss'><button class='icon'>exp</button></li>");
      $("button.icon").attr("id", function(a) {
        return "butn" + a;
      });
      $("button").click(function() {
        $('[id^=cat]').toggleClass("responsive");
      });
    });    
</script>
```

and

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="tab active has-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <span>ep0</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab has-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <span>ep1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul class="nav">
  <li class="tab active has-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <span>ep3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab has-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <span>ep4</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Currently when clicking on the button all `class="nav"` are + "responsive".
I want when click `<butn..>` it just performs an action right there.
But do not know what to do

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking exactly. *"it just performs an action right there."* means what?

Answer (score 1):

`$('[id^=cat]')` will select all elements with an id starting with `cat`.

You need to be more specific. One way to do this would be to use the clicked button itself to find the ancestor `ul`.

Within the `click()` event handler you can use `$(this)` to refer to the button. This means that in order to find the ancestor `ul` you can do this:

```
$(this).closest('ul').toggleClass("responsive");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav").attr("id", function(i) {
    return "cat" + i;
  });
  $("ul.nav").append("<li class='ss'><button class='icon'>exp</button></li>");
  $("button.icon").attr("id", function(a) {
    return "butn" + a;
  });
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').toggleClass("responsive");
  });
});
```

```css
.responsive {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li class="tab active has-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <span>ep0</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab has-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <span>ep1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>


<ul class="nav">
  <li class="tab active has-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <span>ep3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab has-icon">
    <a href="#">
      <span>ep4</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```